# Why does the basic intuition fail here? What is the reason behind it?

Tags: calculus, integration

We know that
$$\int f(ax + b)\,\mathrm dx = \frac1aF(ax + b) + C$$

so while solving
$$\int x^2\,\mathrm dx = \frac13x^3 + C$$

also,
$$\int (x + 3)^4\,\mathrm dx = \frac15(x + 3)^5 + C$$

but for trig functions like, 
$$\int \sin^2x\,\mathrm dx \neq \frac13\sin^3x + C$$

Instead, we have to simplify it first algebraically. So why does the intuition fail here?

Update: I seem to be confused with f. Till now $$\int \sin^2(1*x+0)\,\mathrm dx  \ $$, I have assumed f = (sin(x))^2 with a=1 and b=0. There seems something wrong with my understanding.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), though written in the reverse direction as [$u$-substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).  The shortest answer is that the derivative of $\sin^3 x$ is $3\sin^2 x \cos x$, not $3\sin^2 x$ and that you are not applying the chain-rule properly.

Comment: How are you applying the $f(ax+b)$ rule to $\sin^2x$? What are $f$, $a$, and $b$ here?

Comment: There is no failure of 'basic intuition' here. In the last case of sine function, the antiderivative is not a function one can 'see'/guess without some work.

Comment: Is not it function a function of sine? @AnyAD

Comment: If f is sin, a is 1, and b is 0, then $f(ax+b) = \sin x$. That doesn't seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason why you can't apply your formula here is because with your example:

$$\int (\sin x)^2 \,\mathrm dx$$

Here, $f(x) = x^2$ but the input, $\sin x$, does not fit the format of $ax + b$.

More generally, this is because of the [chain rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). It states that:

$$\left(f(g(x)\right)' = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

In each of your examples, the chain rule creates a situation where you don't necessarily see it, but it's there. For example when $f(x) = 3x^2$ and $g(x) = x + 3$, we try to find the derivative of $f(g(x))$:

$${\mathrm d \over \mathrm dx} {(x+3)^3\over 3} = 3(x + 3)^2 \cdot {\mathrm d \over \mathrm dx} (x + 3)$$

Since the derivative of $x + 3$ is $1$, you can simply apply the reverse power rule for integration. But when the inside does *not* have a derivative of $1$ (or a constant for that matter), you run into problems. For example when $f(x) = \frac 13 x^3$ and $g(x) = \sin x$:

$${\mathrm d \over \mathrm dx} \frac 13 (\sin x)^3 = \frac 13 \cdot 3(\sin x)^2 \cdot {\mathrm d \over \mathrm dx} \sin x = \sin^2 x \cos x$$

You'll notice that $\sin^2 x \cos x\neq \sin^2 x$. The chain rule **always applies**, because you must measure the change in every intermediary function with respect to some variable. See [$u$-substitution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), which is a technique for integration that essentially undoes the chain rule.

Comment: f(x)=x^2,  I thought f(x)=(sin(x))^2

Comment: @Nature If so, then you're left with the same exact problem... if $f(x) = (\sin x)^2$ then you still have to find $F(x)$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$. That leads you nowhere and leaves you with the exact same problem of finding $\int (\sin x)^2 \,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Is not concept of function same everywhere? Not changing according to demand.

Comment: @Nature What do you mean?

Comment: @Nature Where am I changing the concept of a function?

Comment: changing f(x)=(sinx)^2 to f(x)=x^2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75082/discussion-between-nature-and-andrew-li).

Comment: @Nature I am not changing anything. I am simply stating, that, by your formula, $f(x) = x^2$ and $ax + b = \sin x$. That means $f(ax + b) = f(\sin x) = (\sin x)^2$. But as you'll notice we can't put $\sin x$ in terms of $ax + b$ where $a,b$ are constants.

Answer (score 3):

It is not intuition. Your first line is true, $$\int f(ax+b)dx$$ and use the substitution $u=ax+b$ and we get $$\int f(u)du*\frac{1}{a}$$ So far so good. Now if $f(x)=x^3$, then $(x+4)^3=f(x+4)$ hence it fits into our formula and you cna use it. However, if $f(x)=x^2$, then we do not have $a$ and $b$ such that $f(ax+b)=sin(x)^2$ so we cannot use the formula.