# We know $\int x^2\,\mathrm dx = \frac13 x^3+C$, so why isn't $\int \sin^2x\,\mathrm dx =\frac13\sin^3x + C$?

Tags: calculus, integration

At first I would like to apologize to the members who answered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708293/why-does-the-basic-intuition-fail-here-what-is-the-reason-behind-it). [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708293/why-does-the-basic-intuition-fail-here-what-is-the-reason-behind-it) question had considerable information so  I asked different question.

Actual question I wanted to ask,

We know that
$$\int (x + b)^n\,\mathrm dx =\frac{(x+b)^{n+1}}{n+1} + C$$

so while solving
$$\int x^2\,\mathrm dx = \frac13x^3 + C$$

also,
$$\int (x + 3)^4\,\mathrm dx = \frac15(x + 3)^5 + C$$

but for trig functions like, 
$$\int \sin^2x\,\mathrm dx \neq \frac13\sin^3x + C$$

Instead, we have to simplify it first algebraically. So why does the intuition fail here?

I apologize once again. But still I learnt some new things.

Comment: The answers in the linked question are still relevant and the changes between the two questions are not drastic enough to warrant a new post.

Comment: @Nature Do you recall the chain rule?

Comment: What exactly is your intuition? It seems like you're just trying to quickly generalize the power rule - which just doesn't work. If you're trying to figure out why $\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(x)+C$ isn't the antiderivative of $\sin^2(x)$ you could just differentiate.

Comment: Because it should be like: $$\int \sin^2x\,\mathrm d(\sin x) = \frac13\sin^3x + C$$

Comment: @AndrewLi I don't think so. Let's see the OP's opinion.

Comment: @Nature Happy you got your answer and hope you get well very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'nice' form you see from the polynomial integration is a result of a rigorous derivation, which by right isn't supposed to become something 'intuitive'...

Also actually the trigonometric functions have their own polynomial 'equivalents' so to say.

For example,
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}+\cdots$$

This probably would explain why
$$\int \sin^2x\,\mathrm dx \neq \frac13\sin^3x + C$$
since
$$\int \left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}+\cdots\right)^2\,\mathrm dx \neq \frac13\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}+\cdots\right)^3 + C$$

Comment: You're introducing taylor series to someone who is struggling to understand the chain rule.

Comment: @AndrewLi I'm trying to give the trigo function a polynomial 'form' which might make it easier for the OP to see why the 'intuition' doesn't apply. The first step is not to try to forcibly explain chain rule, but is to dispel the thinking that intuition from one place applies to another place in maths...

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat But I would probably think the OP has no idea where the heck this *infinite* polynomial representation even comes from. You're nuking a mosquito.